# Showing that Newton's divided difference formulas are invariant to permutations of points by swapping neigbhoring points

Tags: proof-verification, numerical-methods

This is not the right way to prove that the Newton's divided difference formula is invariant to permutations, I just want to see if this kind of proof could be made to work.

We have a set of points $(x_0, \dots, x_n), x_i < x_{i+1}$, with corresponding function values $f(x_i) = f_i$.

The goal is to show that the [Newton's divided difference formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) is invariant for the permutation of points $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$.

The divided difference of two adjacent points

$f[x_i, x_{i+1}] = \dfrac{f_{i+1} - f_i}{x_{i+1} - x_i}$

If $x_i$ is swapped with $x_{i+1}$

$f[x_{i+1}, x_i] = f[swap(x_i, x_{i+1})] = \dfrac{-(f_{i+1} - f_i)}{-(x_{i+1} - x_i)}=f[x_i, x_{i+1}]$. (1)

A permutation of $(x_0, x_1, \dots, x_i)$ can be defined as a swap operation that exchanges some $x_k, x_l, k < l$. This swap operation can be constructed from two iterative swap operations that operate successively on neighboring points. The first one swaps the argument with forward-adjacent points starting with $x_k, x_{k+1}$ until $x_l$ is replaced by $x_k$.

The second iteration of swaps sends $x_k$ to $x_l$ using backward-adjacent point substitution. This iteration reverses the effect of forward swap operations from the previous step.

*I am not sure how to write this down, here is my attempt*:

$swap(x_k, x_l) = swap_{i=k}^{l-1}(x_i, x_{i+1}), swap_{i=k-1}^{l+1}(x_i, x_{i-1})$

If $k>l$ then the indexes are switched.

Example: Exchange (1,4) by succesive swap operations

Forward swaps $i=[l, k-1], swap(i, i+1)$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
2\\
3\\
4
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2\\
1\\
3\\
4
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2\\
3\\
1\\
4
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Backward swaps $i=[k-1, l+1], swap(i, i-1)$

$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
1
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
2\\
4\\
3\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
4\\
2\\
3\\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$

Because (1) shows that the divided difference formula is invariant for swapping adjacent points, and any permutation of $(x_0, \dots, x_n)$ can be defined using sequences of adjacent point swaps, the divided difference formula is invariant to permutations.

Answer (score 2):

Showing that Newton's Divided formula is permutation invariant in $f[x_{i+1},x_i]$ is not enough to claim that it will work for $f[x_0,x_1,...,x_i,x_{i+1},...x_k]$, cause there will be many terms which will involve $f[x_{i+1},x_i]$ after they are broken down using the recursive formula and there will be parts like $f[x_0,x_1,...,x_i]$ and $f[x_{i+1},...,x_k]$ where $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ are on different terms so swapping $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ will also change these terms and you need to show that it will remain invariant.

Here is my approach: 
We have to show that Newton's Divided formula is permutation invariant, i.e. if $\pi$ is any permutation of {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., k}, then 
$$f[x_0,x_1,x_2,..,x_i,x_{i+1},..,x_k] = f[x_{\pi(0)},x_{\pi(1)},x_{\pi(2)},..,x_{\pi(i+1)},x_{\pi(i)},..,x_{\pi(k)}]$$
We can start by having a look at simple cases (In order to verify that the statement is actually true or not):

- k = 0 : $f[x_0] = f[x_0]$ which is trivially true.
- k = 1 : $f[x_0, x_1] = \frac{f[x_0] - f[x_1]}{x_0 - x_1} = \frac{f[x_1] - f[x_0]}{x_1 - x_0} = f[x_1, x_0]$ so it is permutation invariant under this case.

In general if you see carefully then we can figure out an pattern for the Newton's Divided Difference Formula. Like:

- k = 0: $f[x_0] = f(x_0)$
- k = 1: $f[x_0, x_1] = \frac{f(x_0) - f(x_1)}{x_0 - x_1}$
- k = 2: $f[x_0, x_1, x_2] = \frac{f[x_0,x_1] - f[x_1,x_2]}{x_0 - x_2} = \frac{f(x_0)\cdot(x_1-x_2) - f(x_1)\cdot(x_0-x_2) + f(x_2)\cdot(x_0-x_1)}{(x_0 - x_1)\cdot(x_0 - x_2)\cdot(x_1 - x_2)}$, we can see some pattern building, Let's do one more step
- k =3: $f[x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3] = \frac{f[x_0,x_1, x_2] - f[x_1,x_2,x_3]}{x_0 - x_3} = \frac{f(x_0)\cdot(x_1-x_2)\cdot(x_2-x_3)\cdot(x_1-x_3) - f(x_1)\cdot(x_0-x_2)\cdot(x_2-x_3)\cdot(x_0-x_3) + f(x_2)\cdot(x_0-x_1)\cdot(x_1-x_3)\cdot(x_0-x_3) - f(x_3)\cdot(x_0-x_1)\cdot(x_1-x_2)\cdot(x_0-x_2)}{(x_0 - x_1)\cdot(x_0 - x_2)\cdot(x_0 - x_3)\cdot(x_1-x_2)\cdot(x_1-x_3)\cdot(x_2-x_3)}$

Now the pattern seems clear and we can write in compact notation:
$$f[x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_k] = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{i}\cdot f(x_i)\cdot(\prod_{m=0,m\neq i,i-1}^{k-1}(x_m - x_{m+1}))\cdot(x_c-x_d)}{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\prod_{j=i+1}^{k}(x_i - x_j)}$$
where
$c = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & i\neq 0 \\
      1 & i = 0
\end{array} 
\right. $ and
$d = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      k & i\neq k \\
      k-1 & i = k
\end{array} 
\right. $

Now we can see that interchanging $x_p$ and $x_{p+1}$ in Newton's Divided Difference formula for k terms causes change in only 1 term in the product of the denominator that is $(x_p - x_{p+1})$ changes to $(x_{p+1} - x_p)$ so we can take -1 common and the denominator is now same as it was before the swap. 
Similarly, we can see that in the numerator the position of the $p^{th}$ indexed term and $(p+1)^{th}$ indexed term are interchanged and in all other terms $(x_p - x_{p+1})$ has changed to $(x_{p+1} - x_p)$. Hence, we can again take -1 common and the numerator is now same as it was before swap 
Both the -1 taken out common cancels and we get that Newton's Divided formula is invariant under swap of a pair of adjacent terms. 
Note that **this is enough to prove that the formula is invariant under any permutation as we can represent any permutation as a sequence of adjacent swaps**. 
Hence, **Proved**.